# API macro for making C++ library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am a beginner in C++.

I have created a CMake library project,
and I added 2 libraries, one is called
mosaic (shared) and mosaic_s (static).

And the problem is that how can I use macros to automatically set a macro for __declspec(dllexport)
when building shared library and set it to nothing when building a static one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a symbol in your make file that will tell you if it is shared or not and then you can use the preprocessor like

```
#ifndef SHARED
#define EXPORT
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

and then in your code you would have

```
EXPORT whatever_you_are_exporting
```

and if you have defined `SAHRED` in your make file then `EXPORT` will be `__declspec(dllexport)` and if you have not then `EXPORT` will become nothing.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the solution inspired by your suggestion. I use CMake, and I detect if CMake variable MOSAIC_SHARED is defined, if defined then add a shard library and defined MOSAIC_SHARED macro. Then I detect MOSAIC_SHARED is defined in my public header. Thank you so much!